# Oracle sql split amounts by weeks

Tags: sql, oracle, split

So I have a  table like:

```
    UNIQUE_ID    MONTH
    abc          01
    93j          01
    acc          01
    7as          01
    oks          02
    ais          02
    asi          03
    asd          04
```

etc

I query:

```
select count(unique_id) as amount, month
from table
group by month
```

now everything looks great:

```
    AMOUNT    MONTH
    4         01
    2         02
    1         03
```

etc

is there a way to get oracle to split the amounts by weeks?
the way that the result look something like:

```
    AMOUNT   WEEK
    1        01
    1        02
    1        03
    1        04
```

etc

Comment: Do you have date in this table? If yes, then you can. Else can you visually relate amount with week of month, then oracle can do it.

Comment: How would you determine WEEK if all you have is MONTH?

Comment: i don't have date. I only have month number. It shouldn't be hard to determine the amount of weeks in a month when you take calendar in front of you :). Just wondering is it possible to write a script which would divide monthly amounts equally into weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the year - lets say we go with 2014 then you need to generate all the weeks a year

```
select rownum as week_no
from all_objects
where rownum<53) weeks
```

then state which months contain the weeks (for 2014)

```
select week_no, to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')+7*(week_no-1),'MM') month_no
from
(select rownum as week_no
 from all_objects
 where rownum<53) weeks
```

Then join in your data

```
select week_no,month_no, test.unique_id from (
select week_no, to_char(to_date('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')+7*(week_no-1),'MM') month_no
from
(select rownum as week_no
 from all_objects
 where rownum<53) weeks) wm
join test on wm.month_no = test.tmonth
```

This gives your data for the each week as you described above. You can redo your query and count by week instead of month.

Comment: this is great but after joining the inital data to the weeks query things get messed up. what happens is that instead of the result i was expecting: week 1: amount 1, week 2: amount 1, week 3: amount 1 etc. I get the same amount for every week. which means the actual amount for a month would be 4-5 times the original (depending on the amount of weeks in a month). It should divide the monthly sum between the weeks. Now saying that I just got an idea how to fix it. I'll post back when successful...

Comment: basically what i did is I divided the monthly amount by the number of weeks in a month. it's working lika charm, thanks!